# How to Control Keyboard and Mouse like UAC window

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++

Can anyone kindly help me out? 
I want to create an app, like user access control(UAC) application. When UAC is running we cannot click anywhere on the screen, unless we close UAC window. Also we cannot press any key to do anything, like window key or any of the function key. So I want to create a similar application using C ++ code to control keyboard and mouse, that only mouse and keyboard is enabled in my application window and disable outside and unless i do not close my app i cant perform any other task. My application would be just a graphical simple window with a close button, and obove mentioned controls.

Comment: What would happen if two or more apps like yours were running at the same time, and each one insisted that ONLY THEIR app can accept input, blocking input to all other applications?

Comment: Actualy that i want to do, like i want to stop all other apps when my application is running. Try user access control application window. It is whenevr we want to install a new software, and window asks permission from user. When UAC is window is open at our desktop, we cannot click anywhere on the desktop screen, or we cannot press any key to do anything unless we close UAC. same i wana do.

Comment: I understand you want to block other applications.  And what if another application wants to block your application too?  Either you will both be blocked forever, or neither application will be blocked.  This is exactly why what you are asking is impossible, and highly ill advised.  In a multi-tasking OS, a User-Mode program that can block other applications is considered *malicious*.

Comment: I want to create an application, just to try controlling things, i am not having any fight with applications or programs :) I have searched and i can do this using hook functions, thing is i m unable to implement, thats why i m asking for code help. If you can help me, thats so nice of u.

Comment: "What if two programs did this?"  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

I recommend you do **not** reply until you've read this article completely, and thought through the implications for your situation.

Comment: What's the purpose of your application ? Maybe you should consider some kiosk software (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software).

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago Windows supported system modal dialogs. These would prevent the user from interacting with other windows including the desktop. Microsoft removed support for this a long time ago due to the problems that it caused.

Now when Windows needs to provide a system modal window for UAC they use a bit of *desktop* magic. To simulate a system modal window UAC does something like this.

- Create a bitmap and take a snapshot of the current desktop.
- Darken the bitmap
- Create a new desktop
- Set the new desktop as the currently active one.
- Create a window the size of the new desktop and draw the bitmap in it.

Now they have a desktop that *looks* like the old and acts as if it were a system model window. You are then free to create a child window to grab input from the user. The example below shows how to create a desktop and switch to it and should be a good starting point for what you want to do

```
// TODO: Make a copy of the current desktop

// Prepeare a new desktop and activate it
HDESK oldDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
HDESK desktop = CreateDesktop(L"MyDesktop", NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
SwitchDesktop(desktop);

// TODO: Create the window that draws the snapshot of the old desktop

// TODO: Create a dialog with buttons and stuff

// Since we don't have a window sit for 5 seconds staring at blank screen
Sleep(5000);

//  Switch back to the old desktop and destroy the one we created
//  ALERT: If we crash or exit without doing this you will need to
//  restart windows
SwitchDesktop(oldDesktop);
CloseDesktop(desktop);
```

You can find more information on the [desktop related API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)